# How to reimplement an inheriting event handler?

Tags: c#, event-handling

```
public class A : Form
{
  buttonOK;
}
public class B : A
{
}
```

the click event of `buttonOK` in class A has a handler `buttonOK_Click`, I want to invalidate it in class B and add a new click event handler for `buttonOK`.

Can I just set the accessibility of `buttonOK_Click` in class A as `protected` and use `new` keyword to hide it in class B ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A derived class can't just "reach into" a base class and change the implementation. The best you can do is to make the event handler `virtual` in the base class, then you can override it in the derived class.

Answer (score 3):

Use "New" keyword will break the registration of button click event, thus your buttonOK_click in class B would not be executed.
Two common practices are:

1 Declare buttonOK_client in base class as virtual and override it in derived class.

2 Introduce Validate virtual function in base class and provide different implementation   in base and derived class:

```
 public class A : Form
 {
    void buttonOK(...)
    {
        if (Validate())
        {
            //...
        }
    }

    virtual bool Validate()
    {
        //...
    }
 }
 public class B : A
 {
    override bool Validate()
    {
        //...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with John, making the button Click event `virtual` should be the best option.

Here is an example..

```
public partial class Base : Form
{
    public Base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected virtual void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("From Base");
    }
}

public class Derived: Base
{
    protected override void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("From Derived");
    }
}
```